# Cassandra Keyspace system_schema does not exist

Tags: cassandra

I am getting the error that Cassandra keyspace system_schema does not exist. Why this happens and how to resolve it?

```
SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces;
```

> ```
> InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Keyspace system_schema does not exist"
> ```

I follow the command from [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/cassandra_create_keyspace.htm) exactly. But it does not turn out successfully. I worry if I missed anything during the installation process.

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you on?